# How to Parse and get the number of key appearing in the Value side? The Count should be 7

Tags: java

> ```
> {name={doc_count_error_upper_bound=0.0, sum_other_doc_count=0.0,
> buckets=[{key=x, doc_count=165324.0}, {key=y, doc_count=100875.0},
> {key=z, doc_count=99981.0}, {key=A, doc_count=76631.0}, {key=B,
> doc_count=68793.0}, {key=C, doc_count=50717.0}, {key=D,
> doc_count=50034.0}]}
> ```

Here name is the key and right side after `{` is a value. How can I parse and get the number of "key" counts in value side?

```
Map primaryMap= (Map) result.getJsonMap().get("aggregations");

Iterator it = primaryMap.entrySet().iterator();
Map.Entry<String,String> pair=null;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " **********" + pair.getValue());
    it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
}

String value= pair.getValue();
String arrr[]=value.split(",");
System.out.println(value);
int senderValue=0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrr.length; i++){
    if(arrr[i].contains("key")==true);   
        senderValue++;
}
```

When I run the above code I get this kind of exception:

> ```
> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-web] in context with path [/Reports] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
> exception is java.lang.ClassCastException:
> com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to
> java.lang.String] with root cause
>     java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to
> java.lang.String
> ```

Comment: String value= pair.getValue();
    String arrr[]=value.split(",");
    System.out.println(value);
    int senderValue=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrr.length; i++){
     if(arrr[i].contains("key")==true);   
              senderValue++;
              }
    /*  return senderValue;*/
 System.out.println("sendervalue"+senderValue); The problem is unable to parse map

Comment: @Sudheer - So you just want the number of times `key` is repeated?

Comment: Also, please edit the question and add code there.

Comment: Yes Just number of Key counts  in The Value side

Comment: So the count should be 7?

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "{name={doc_count_error_upper_bound=0.0, sum_other_doc_count=0.0, buckets=[{key=x, doc_count=165324.0}, {key=y, doc_count=100875.0}, {key=z, doc_count=99981.0}, {key=A, doc_count=76631.0}, {key=B, doc_count=68793.0}, {key=C, doc_count=50717.0}, {key=D, doc_count=50034.0}]}";
        int i = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (i < s.length()) {
            i = s.indexOf("key", i);
            if (i != -1) {
                count++;
                i++;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
```

O/P : 7